# Is there a way to create dynamic aggregate function in Power BI DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem with Power BI and I would like to get help. My table is like this

| Branch | Year | Sales | Share of Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maca | 2019 | 13K |  |
| Abdo | 2019 | 10K |  |
| Weto | 2020 | 15K |  |
| Roro | 2020 | 30K |  |
| Roro | 2019 | 10K |  |

On the Share of sales column, I will divide sales by sum of sales. But I need it to be dynamic as When I choose 2019 on visual slicer, The column should divide the sales by the sum of Sales column filtered to 2019. The same way, when I choose 2019 and Roro branch on the slicer, the numbers need to be divided by sum of sales filtered to 2019 and Roro branch. In a nutshell, the denominator should be dynamic with visual slicers. I used the method of ISFILTERED function with sum aggregate measure, but It didn't work for me. I would be happy if you can help me with this issue. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a measure like this (where `Table` is the name of your table):

```
Share of Sales = SUM('Table'[Sales]) / SUMX(ALLSELECTED('Table'), 'Table'[Sales])
```

So if there is no filter applied, it will look like this:

[image]

When it is filtered by year, like this:

[image]

And when it is filtered by year and branch, like this:

[image]

[ALLSELECTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) function will remove the context filters, but will retain the explicit filters (e.g. slicers), so `SUMX(ALLSELECTED('Table'), 'Table'[Sales])` will give you the total sales of the all the data shown at this moment. `SUM('Table'[Sales])` on the other hand will calculate the total sales in the current context, i.e. data row or totals row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I was not aware that I can use measure as a column in a visual